# when to use openid.ax.required inopenid

Tags: openid, openid-provider

when to use openid.ax.required in making request for authentication.Because if this option is required by google but it is not required by yahoo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's *never* required to use AX. Google doesn't require it, neither does yahoo, or any other provider.

AX is an extension allowing you to fetch additional data, like user's name, or email.
`openid.ax.required` contains fields that you'd like to fetch and mark as required fields, that's it.

For more information, read the [Attribute Exchange](http://openid.net/specs/openid-attribute-exchange-1_0.html) specification.